# Visual Studio 2022: How to access the built in "Developer PowerShell" instead of the Windows PowerShell?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, you can open the Developer PowerShell from `Tools>Command Line>Developer PowerShell`
In the previous versions of Visual Studio, it used to open the built in PowerShell window:
[image]

I can still access this if I use my old window layouts. So it still exists.

However, In VS 2022, if I try to open it from `Tools>Command Line>Developer PowerShell`, it just opens up a separate window:
[image]
Is there any way to open the built-in Developer PowerShell in VS 2022 without using old window layouts?

Comment: Both my 2019 and 2022 versions of Visual Studio open powershell in its own window.

Comment: @TimothyG. may I ask which version of VS 2022 you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2022 Comm.
Right click project in Solution Explorer to open context menu, there you will find "Open in Terminal" command.

Answer (score 22):

In a newer version of VS 2022, the Developer PowerShell has been moved to `View > Terminal` it seems. Confusingly, `Tools > Command Line >`**`Developer PowerShell`** opens up the Windows PowerShell.

[Learn more at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022)

Edit: It seems there's a new Developer PowerShell now that is accessible from the start menu as a separate executable. This is what opens up if you try to open Developer PowerShell from `Tools` in VS. The confusion comes from the integrated "terminal" still being named "Developer PowerShell".

Comment: The naming and menu layout is so confusing. As far as I can tell, 'Developer' just means they have set some env vars for you, and it's still just the system-installed powershell.exe or cmd.exe. And the two different menu locations just correspond to 'open in VS dockable panel' or 'open in separate window'. I wish all the menu entries were in the same place and were explicit about what you get.

Answer (score 0):

The developer command line tools are installed here:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\'
```

You can view the `VsDevCmd.bat` batch file or `Launch-VsDevShell.ps1` PowerShell script to see what they do. In short, they are scripts that are invoked by the default Windows system programs. PowerShell, for example, is located here:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\'
```

It's worth noting that they do not define the same environment variables, which is rather annoying.